# Error when adding ADO.NET Entity Data Model ( MySQL )

Tags: c#, mysql, wpf, entity-framework, entity-framework-6

I created a new WPF project using MySQL and EntityFramework in VS2019.I installed MySQL:

[image]

When I use this code in app.config

```
<provider invariantName="MySql.Data.MySqlClient" type="MySql.Data.MySqlClient.MySqlProviderServices, MySql.Data.EntityFramework" />
```

The Wizard will crash. After Click Next

[image]

But with :

```
<provider invariantName="MySql.Data.MySqlClient" type="MySql.Data.MySqlClient.MySqlProviderServices, MySql.Data.EntityFramework, Version=8.0.23.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=c5687fc88969c44d"></provider>
```

I faced this problem

[image]

Please save me :((

Comment: Off-topic, it's strongly discouraged to work with EDMX for new code. Use the "code first from database" approach.

Comment: follow this guide: https://dev.mysql.com/doc/connector-net/en/connector-net-entityframework60.html .

Comment: @magicandre1981 i had followed that guide before went here to ask this topic. Somewhere, i saw that the guide maybe wrong ...

Comment: have you made all steps? Is machine.config updated with the DbProviderFactories entry?

Comment: i used nuget to install package instead it. But i tried it in one time, i didn''t working

Comment: you need to follow all steps. use the MSI to install the .net provider, next the Visual Studio DDEX provider, add the nuget, add the changes to app.config. If you miss steps it doesn't work.